# Java - Class cannot see object in other class

Tags: java, class

I am facing a common compilation error with Cannot find symbols in java. The methods from the class Product cannot be used in the main class. The code is below. I have tried to pass the class in any possible ( to my knowledge means) but with no luck.

The error i get is:

```
CashRegisterTester.java:108: error: cannot find symbol
        double iprice = products[i].getPrice();
                        ^
  symbol:   variable products
  location: class CashRegister
1 error
```

Here's the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class CashRegisterTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Product[] products = new Product[5];

        products[0] = new Product();
        products[0].setCode(0);
        products[0].setName("psomi");
        products[0].setPrice(0.50);

        products[1] = new Product();
        products[1].setCode(1);
        products[1].setName("gala");
        products[1].setPrice(1.30);

        products[2] = new Product();
        products[2].setCode(2);
        products[2].setName("mila");
        products[2].setPrice(1.80);

        products[3] = new Product();
        products[3].setCode(3);
        products[3].setName("zaxari");
        products[3].setPrice(2.40);

        products[4] = new Product();
        products[4].setCode(4);
        products[4].setName("krasi");
        products[4].setPrice(13.20);


        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            System.out.println("\n Product code: " + products[i].getCode() + " \n Product Name: " + products[i].getName() + "\n Product Price: " + 
                    products[i].getPrice());

        System.out.println("Which product would you like to buy?");
        Scanner myscanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int iEntered;
        iEntered = myscanner.nextInt();

        CashRegister register = new CashRegister(products);

        register.recordPurchase(iEntered);

        System.out.println("Would you like to buy something more? [y/n]");
        String answer;
        answer = myscanner.next();


        while (answer.equals('y')) {
            System.out.println("Which product would you like to buy?");

            register.recordPurchase(iEntered);

            System.out.println("Would you like to buy something more? [y/n]");
            answer = myscanner.next();

        }

        System.out.println("How much money will you give?");

        double pay = myscanner.nextDouble();
        register.enterPayment(pay);

        double change = register.giveChange();
        System.out.println(change);

        // register.finalReceipt();


    }

}
```

---

```
class Product{

    //Product fields
    public int code;
    public String name;
    public double price;


    //Getters & setters
    public int getCode(){
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int scode){
        code = scode;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String sname){
        name = sname;
    }

    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double sprice){
        price = sprice;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CashRegister extends Product{


    public CashRegister(Product[] products){
        purchase = 0;
        payment = 0;
    }

    public void recordPurchase(int i){
        double iprice = products[i].getPrice;
        double total = purchase + iprice;
        purchase = total;
    }

    public void enterPayment(double amount){
        payment = amount;
    }

    public double giveChange(){
        double change = payment - purchase;
        purchase = 0;
        payment = 0;
        return change;
    }

    private double purchase;
    private double payment;

}
```

Comment: your question is unclear for me which function you called ,and where is the error? Try adding more explanation

Comment: How exactly are you compiling these classes? Using `javac` on the command line? (if so, give details) or in an IDE?

Comment: Here's the javac error:

CashRegisterTester.java:108: error: cannot find symbol
  double iprice = products[i].getPrice();
                  ^
  symbol:   variable products
  location: class CashRegister
1 error

Comment: @falsobuio Why do you think, that the local variable `products` can be used in an arbitrary place?

Comment: @Tom, obviously because he's new to Java programming. Be nice.

Comment: I have added the error i get. I am missing something that i need your advise! Thanks

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) to know what _local variables_ are and then change `register.recordPurchase(iEntered);` to `register.recordPurchase(iEntered, products);` and `public void recordPurchase(int i){` to `public void recordPurchase(int i, Product[] products){`. And before you ask `double iprice = products[i].getPrice;` should be `double iprice = products[i].getPrice();`.

Comment: Why does `CashRegister` extend `Product`?  Last I checked, a cash register isn't a type of Product in most stores - unless you're selling cash registers, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The `products` variable is declared nowhere. This is why you get this exception.

Declare `products` as a private member of the CashRegister class and initialize it in the `CashRegister` constructor. See the code below:

```
public class CashRegister extends Product {

    public CashRegister(Product[] products){
        purchase = 0;
        payment = 0;
        this.products=products; // Initialize private member
    }

    public void recordPurchase(int i){
        double iprice = products[i].getPrice();
        double total = purchase + iprice;
        purchase = total;
    }

    public void enterPayment(double amount){
        payment = amount;
    }

    public double giveChange(){
        double change = payment - purchase;
        purchase = 0;
        payment = 0;
        return change;
    }

    private double purchase;
    private double payment;
    private Product[] products; // Declare private member
}
```

One last note, to prevent resource leaks, NEVER forget to close a `Scanner`.
So add `myscanner.close();` at the end of the `main` method in the `CashRegister` class.